# Dropdown select option selenium webdriverjs

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to select a option from select by the value of the option, not the attribute.
HTML:

```
<select id="size">
   <option>S</select>
   <option>M</select>
   <option>L</select>
</select>
```

I already have this on javascript, its when i visit the page, then it clicks the dropdown, but how do i select an option?

```
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    await driver.get("index.html");
    await driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Blue Shirt")).click();

    let size = By.id("size");
    let waitForSize = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(size));
    await waitForSize.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic selector to click the option.

ex:

```
var value = "S";
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='size']/option[contains(text(), " + value + ")]")).click();
```

or you can do a for to loop through all the `//select[@id='size']/option` elements, extract its text, and if it matches your option, click the element and break the for

```
for (var element in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//select[@id='size']/option]"))) {
    if (element.getText() === value) {
        element.click();
        break;
    }
}
```